# Bad space before quote (due to line spacing)

Tags: spacing, csquotes

I use `csquotes` for dealing with my quotes. Unfortunately I use different line spacing in the text (1.5) and in the quote (1.). The result is a too large space before the quote.
Is there any possibility to correct it?

**MWE:**

```
 \documentclass{article}   

\usepackage[main=french,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay=true]{csquotes} 
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\singlespacing}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quotation\expandafter{\quotation\singlespacing}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing

\lipsum*[1]
\hyphenblockquote{french}{\lipsum*[1]}
\lipsum*[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using `\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\singlespacing}` you could as well use `\edef\qote{\quote\noexpand\singlespacing}` and if you're redefining `\quote` and `\quotation` to use `\singlespacing` you could as well include a negative `\vspace` in that definition as well.

Comment: @Skillmon Do I have to load a specific package for your command beacause it does not work...

Comment: No you haven't, the problem is, that you only need one expansion, so my command was just wrong in this case.

Comment: @Skillmon :-) ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have used the following syntax:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}
```

`0.75`correspond to the correcting space for going from `\onehalfspacing` in the text and `\singlespacing` in the quotes